# NHibernate querying on any-associations meta-value

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a collection of entities with an any-association, like this:

```
public class CreatedLog
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public EntityBase CreatedEntity { get; set; } // an association to any entity
}
```

Is there a way - through HQL or Criteria API - to find only the log entries, that are for a specific entity-type?

Like

```
session.CreateCriteria<CreatedLog>()
.Add(Restriction.Eq("CreatedEntityType", "Note"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the special `class` property:

```
from CreatedLog c where c.CreatedEntity.class = 'YourSpecificClass'
```

Comment: Nice! That's looks like a way to go. Do you know if it has an eqvivalent in the criteria api?

Comment: @asgerhallas, I don't know if this is possible with Criteria API. Maybe someone could bring more insight.

Comment: I just did it like this: Restriction.Eq("CreatedEntity.class", "YourSpecificClass")

Comment: @asgerhallas, that's great, didn't know this was possible. Thanks.